# What is the need of recursive update or paint in order to paint lightweight component?

Tags: java, swing, recursion, awt, paint

I am reading [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#) article on Painting in AWT and Swing which have following paragraph in section *"How lightweights get painted"*

> It's worth noting that the default implementation of Container.update() does not use recursion to invoke update() or paint() on lightweight descendents. This means that any heavyweight Container subclass that uses update() to do incremental painting must ensure that lightweight descendents are recursively repainted if necessary. Fortunately, few heavyweight container components need incremental painting, so this issue doesn't affect most programs.

Please tell me, in which case do I need to have recursive calls to update() or paint() and why?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need recursive calls to update() or paint().

If you want to paint a component all you do is:

```
component.repaint();
```

This will add a paint request to the `RepaintManager` to paint the component and Swing will make sure that the components child components get painted when the `paintChildren(...)` method is invoked. See [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) for more information.

Comment: but what about this paragraph, I know this repaint() thing, but I am unable to understand the above lines.why so?

Comment: Why do you care? What issues are you having? Don't use AWT components in a Swing application. I don't know what it means but I'm guessing it is saying that if you add an Swing component to an AWT component you will have trouble painting the Swing component because Swing relies on the `paintChildren(...)` to make sure child components are painted.